# Select segments of the same name in d3.js sunburst

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highlight, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to adjust this example http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426:

[image]

so that the hover over selects all segments of the same name instead of the ancestors of the current segment.

This is the script

```
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}
```

Thank you kindly for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you mentioned in the question should be replaced with the following code:

```
  var currentName = d.name;
  vis.selectAll("path")
      .filter(function(node) {
                return (node.name == currentName);
              })
      .style("opacity", 1);
}
```

The effect is shown here: *([demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2M9E/) is also available; this is somewhat scaled down version of the original example that I used for debugging; also, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3WLmR/) is the version with original highlighting, if you can make use of it)*

[image]

Comment: @FernOfTheAndes, nice to see you!